# how to pass ArrayList in a constructor to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to java and trying to work on ArrayList. From Main method I want to >pass the ArrayList to another class CustomerAcc. I need help how to pass the >ArrayList and then how to get the ArrayList in the class Customer code here

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object;

public class CustomerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> custName = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> custZip = new ArrayList<String>();
        double count = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter Customer name or 'X' to exit: ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Gets user input for name and zip code             
        while (in.hasNext() && !done) {
            String checkInput = in.next();

            if (checkInput.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                custName.add(checkInput);

                System.out.print("Please enter Zip code: ");
                custZip.add(in.next());
                count++;

                System.out.print("\nPlease enter Customer Name or 'X' to `enter code here`exit: ");
            }
        }
        //Sending the user input data to CustomerAcc class
        CustomerAcc custRecord = new CustomerAcc(custName, custZip, count);
    }
}
```

The CustomerAcc class :

```
public class CustomerAcc extends CustomerMain {

   public static void CustomerAcc(String custName, String custZip, int count){

   }
}
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well that you want to access an ArrayList in another class? if in the case, you can use the getter and setter technique while declaring private ArrayList variables.

```
private ArrayList<String> custName = new ArrayList<String>();  
private ArrayList<String> custZip = new ArrayList<String>();  



public void setCustName(ArrayList custName){
    this.custName = custName;
}

public ArrayList geCustName(){
    return custName;
}


public void setCustZip(ArrayList custZip){
    this.custZip = custZip;
}

public ArrayList geCustZip(){
    return custZip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change constructor of your `CustomerAcc` class to:

```
 public CustomerAcc(ArrayList<String> custName, ArrayList<String> custZip, int count){

}
```

Also you have defined your custName and custZip as

```
     ArrayList custName = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList custZip = new ArrayList();
```

which is incorrect. You have to specify type of objects in your ArrayList (I suppose they are strings now.)

Define it like:

```
 ArrayList<String> custName = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax while speaking you can change your constructor code definition to -

```
public CustomerAcc(ArrayList<String> custName, ArrayList<String> custZip, int count){

}
```

Looking at your code, you could have used `Map<String, String>` for storing username and its zip, instead of using two lists.

On a separate note, Are you sure you're building single CustomerAcc object taking list of customers and their zipcodes as input?

Comment: Hi Raman, I am working on my college project where I have customers first name, last name and the zip code. Then I have to write the info into the file. Before I could start on the project work I was trying to get information into the ArrayList.